# Transforming Python list of tuples to R named vector

Tags: python, r, shiny, reticulate

I have python reticulate function which returns list of two length tuples of type `(id, name)`.

```
# In the python API
returned_list = [
    (1, "Jon Doe"),
    (2, "Jane Doe"),
]
```

```
library(shiny)
library(reticulate)
# source and other staff

API <- pythonAPI()
values <- API.call() # Returns R list of 2 length lists
values
#   [,1]   [,2] 
# [1,] List,2 List,2
for(index in 1:length(values)){
    message(values[index])
# list(1, "Jon Doe")
# list(2, "Jane Doe")
```

This `values` list is supposed to go as choices for `shiny`'s `selectInput` `choices` parameter. This `choices` parameter should have `name` as the value shown to the user and `id` as hidden value processed in the program.

```
selectInput("_id", "Choose name", choices)
```

How to transform `values` returned from Python API to fit use-case?

Comment: Please provide some data.

Comment: I added more clear definition of the returned data types as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My coworker managed to come up with solution.

```
# Create dataframe scaffold
df <- data.frame("name" = NA, "id" = NA)
# Bind values from values to the scaffold by rows
for (i in seq(values)) {
    df_tmp <- rbind.data.frame(values[[i]])
    colnames(df_tmp) <- c("name", "id")
    df <- rbind(df, df_tmp)
}

## Remove empty first row
df <- df[!is.na(df$name),]
    ​
# Transform to right format for shinyapp UI
choices <- setNames(df$name, df$id)
```